# Typo3 Form Validation - Allowed File Types and Maximum File Size

Tags: forms, typo3

Is it possible to validate a typo3 (vers. 7.6.23) form for allowed file types (in my example only *.pdf) and maximum file size (in my example maximum 5mb)? Maybe with the rules function?

My form looks like this:

```
enctype = multipart/form-data
method = post
prefix = tx_form
confirmation = 
postProcessor {
    1 = mail
    1 {
        recipientEmail = xxx@xxx.de
        senderEmail = formmailer@xxx.de
        subject = email subject
    }
}
...  
40 = FIELDSET
40 {
    20 = FILEUPLOAD
    20 {
        type = file
        name = Anschreiben
        label {
            value = Anschreiben
        }
    }
}
...

rules {
    1 = required
    1 {
        showMessage = 
        message = Benötigt
        error = Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld
        element = Vorname
    }
    2 = required
    2 {
        showMessage = 
        message = Benötigt
        error = Dies ist ein Pflichtfeld
        element = Nachname
    }
    3 = email
    3 {
        showMessage = 
        message = (max.muster@domain.com)
        error = Dies ist keine gültige E-Mail-Adresse
        element = E-Mail
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Thank you for pointing me towards FileAllowedTypesValidator and FileMaximumSizeValidator.

I tried adding the idea to the rules:

```
rules {

    4 = fileallowedtypes 
        4 { 
                breakOnError = 0 
                showMessage = 
                message = (%allowedTypes) 
                error = only pdf please!
                types = application/pdf
                element = Anschreiben 
        } 
    5 = filemaximumsize 
        5 { 
                breakOnError = 0 
                showMessage = 
                message = The file has to be smaller as %maximum 
                error = file is too big!
                maximum = 5242880 
                element = Anschreiben 
        } 

}
```

Since I have more than one FileUpload-Field i added those two rules for every field. The query now works and I get an error when I upload the wrong file type or a file bigger than 5 MB.

Only problem is, that i cant leave the FileUpload-Fields empty; i always get the "wrong filetype" error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below typoscript.

```
plugin.tx_form {
    settings {
       registeredValidators {
        fileallowedtypes {
            displayName = Allowed mimetypes for file
            className = TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Validator\FileAllowedTypesValidator
        }

        filemaximumsize {
            displayName = Maximum size for file (bytes)
            className = TYPO3\CMS\Form\Domain\Validator\FileMaximumSizeValidator
        }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing my in the direction of fileallowedtypes and filemaximumsize. I added those two querys to the rules, but it seems that fileallowedtypes also prompts an error message when no file is uploaded. in my case the user should have the option to leave all or some file-upload-fields empty.